Book recommendation for an author that would treat Riemann integrability when $f$ is not necessarily bounded
The two books I have learnt Riemann integrability with (Mathematical Analysis by T. Apostol and PMA by W. Rudin) carefully state at the beginning of their integrability chapter that we work with bounded functions on $[a,b]$.
The (second) example provided in this answer to a post of my own gives an example of a non-continuous function admitting a primitive. If it admits a primitive, it hence is Riemann integrable (by the second Fundamental Theorem of Calcul).
My question is, provided the example given is unbounded around $0$, do you know any book that treats the case of Riemann integrability of unbounded functions ?
Thanks in advance.

By definition Riemann integrability only deals with bounded functions (and for good reason). Anything else is handled by the improper Riemann integral, which I’m sure Rudin and Apostol cover (though in hindsight this is just an adhoc fix; a much more systematic approach is given by Lebesgue’s integral).

Having a primitive doesn't imply being Riemann integrable. The theorem you are perhaps referring to states if $f$ has a primitive $F$ in $[a,b]$ and also is Riemann integrable then $\int_a^b f=F(b)-F(a)$. So just having a primitive is not sufficient. The whole theory of Riemann integration is based on the function being bounded, otherwise Darboux sums will not even make sense.
Anyway, there is a very natural generalization of the Riemann integral to unbounded functions and unbounded intervals, called improper integrals. You should be able to find it in pretty much any book about Riemann integrals, probably as the next chapter. So for example, the example in the link is a function that has a convergent improper integral.
